# Same relative width in fixed header and content

Tags: html, css

Please find my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/5jv8m5xf/

The code above consists of a **fixed header** and a **content**.

I want that the **fixed header** and the **content** have the same **relative width (%)**. Therefore, I put `width: 80%;` for both of them. However, as you can see in the JSFiddle the **fixed header** has a bigger width than the **content**.

When I put a fixed width (px) for example `width: 500px;` for both of them they have exactly the same width. However, I want them to have the same **relative width (%)** to make the layout responsive.

What do I have to change in my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default browser styles add `8px` of `margin` to the `<body>` element.

Those are offsetting your `.content`, but won't effect the `.header`, because it's fixed.

Add this to align your elements:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfect.